# Phantomjs Add text

Tags: html, text, phantomjs, screen

I am trying to add text on screenshot. So my code is:

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var WebPage = require('webpage');

page = WebPage.create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 480, height: 800 };
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 };
page.open(args[1].toString());
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
page.render(args[1] + '.png');
phantom.exit();
}
```

I want to know how can i modify html content before rendering in order to add some text? I tried to use page.content but unsuccessfully.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify html content with function "page.evaluate". With the function you can run a javascript on the page. Some simple examples can be found at http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html.

Try to add something like the statement below before the render:

```
page.evaluate(function(str) {
    document.querySelector('h2').textContent = str;
}, 'title');
```